# Question closed for reasons I find inaccurate

Tags: discussion

At times, I conceive of  questions   that are   vaguely related to more common ones, but entailing much more nuance than generally captured in basic references or guides. In some cases,  the answer may be found in advanced sources, but locating it would require specific expertise  exceeding my limitations.

Recently, I posted [such a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/598581).

It was closed.

Why?

The advice given by the template message is that the question  is inappropriate due to the following  characterizations:

- It is  is off topic.
- It is appropriate for English learners.
- It may be answered through common references.
- It might have been presented along with  more comprehensive research.

Without presenting a full rebuttable, I would suggest that  every point is   largely incorrect as applied to my question. Even the one I consider most sound in principle, the final, may apply for someone who has greater knowledge than I, but seeking such knowledge from others is the purpose of asking questions. No obvious method presents for finding   an answer in any reference, advanced or basic, based solely on the content contained in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to reöpen your question. I don’t believe it is well answered here. The would-be duplicates seem mostly to mindlessly repeat the same old tired mistakes.

Here are some references to get people started on providing an actual answer: [1](https://arnoldzwicky.org/2011/10/23/whichthat/), [2](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2425), [3](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3519), [4](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=183), [5](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=5479), [6](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emyl/languagelog/archives/000918.html).

Comment: It isn't really well-asked, either.  It's simply not clear what distinction is asked for.